# Is the Cantor set $2^{\omega_1}$ separable?

Tags: general-topology

A space is by definition separable if it contains a countable dense set. Is the Cantor space $2^{\omega_1}$ separable?

I would think not, because $2^{\omega_1}$ has an uncountable base of clopen sets, but I want to be sure.

Comment: How do you interpret the cantor set as $2^{\omega_1}$? Or is it a different object from the well-known subset of the real numbers?

Comment: @supinf It's a so-called Cantor cube, a power of $2=\{0,1\}$. It's a standard name. The Cantor comes from the Cantor set in $[0,1]$ being homeomorphic to $2^\omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a corollary of the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem the product of $\mathfrak c$ many separable spaces is separable, so since $\{0,1\}$ is separable and $\mathfrak c\geq\omega_1$, we have that $2^{\omega_1}$ is separable.

Note that the usual Cantor set as a subspace of the reals is homeomorphic to $2^\omega$ rather than $2^{\omega_1}$ however.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you very much!